# Cordova/Phonegap - Facebook login... Can I use the same javascript code as my Web App?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

My web app uses the below code for authenticating users - it works great:

```
//functionality I'm using for my web-app
FB.init({
    appId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true,
    version: 'v2.4'
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response){
    //auth/de-auth... etc...
};
```

Now I'm wrapping my code with Phonegap and am hoping to use my existing code (or update my code to handle both web app and Cordova) situations.

- https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/
- https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Both respond with `Can't find variable: FB`, I was expecting the plugin to override the `FB.` functions to use the plugin instead but that's not happening.

How do i need to modify my js so it works both for the web app and one of the cordova plugins?

Many thanks